# WHERE clause IN (array) doesn't extract any data despite array exists

Tags: excel, vba

Under Column P in the ActiveWorkbook, user to input a range of data from P2 to lastrow. These range of data in Column P are then assigned to an array variable called myRange.

The power query should pull data from closed workbook's Column [something] if matches with the values in myRange. Below is the code I came up with:

```
Sub grabdata()

    Dim qt As QueryTable
    Dim qName As String
    Dim connString As String, sSql As String, Filepath As String, sourceshname As String
    Dim targetsh As Worksheet
    
    qName = "PowerQueryData"
    Filepath = Sheets("Sheet9").Range("C18").Value
    sourceshname = "Sheet1"
    
    Set targetsh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("TEST")
    
    Dim myRange As Variant
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    
    ' Find last used range in header row
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Assign header row to an array for loop
    myRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("P2:P" & Lastrow).Value

    If Filepath <> "" Then
        sSql = "SELECT * FROM [" & sourceshname & "$] WHERE [something] IN ("" & Join(myRange, "", "") & "")"
        Debug.Print sSql
        connString = "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & Filepath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
        Set qt = targetsh.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=connString, Destination:=targetsh.Range("A1"), Sql:=sSql)
        With qt
            .Name = qName
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
            .MaintainConnection = False
            .AdjustColumnWidth = False
            .Delete
        End With
    End If

End Sub
```

No issue with the syntax I suppose. It works to pull all data but wouldn't extract any data when the WHERE condition is added.

EDIT: I troubleshot and found out 1 problem. Suppose all data columns are connected, Column A has data till row 500 whilst Column P has data till row 5.

```
    Dim myRange As Range
    Dim cell As Variant, myArr As Variant
    Dim Lastrow As Long

    ' Find last used range in header row
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Assign header row to an array for loop
    Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet9").Range("P2:P & Lastrow")
    myArr = myRange
    
    For Each cell In myArr
        Debug.Print cell
    Next cell
```

If I used the above to assign values in Column P to an array, it will only return the values in cell P1 and P2.

On the other hand, if I were to use this line to specify the exact range:

```
    Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet9").Range("P2:P5")
```

It will return the values in cell P2 to P5. I've no clue what's gone wrong with this array thingy.

Nevertheless, I only managed to fix one part of problem. Believe something is wrong (prolly syntax) with the SQL statement particularly the WHERE clause.

Comment: Be aware _Cells(Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row_ refers to the active sheet and not necessarily to your _Sheet9_

Comment: Thanks so much! I have since set the worksheet and assign with block for that line of code. The array is now working fine. Am still troubleshooting the SQL statement..

Comment: `sSql = "SELECT * FROM [" & sourceshname & "$] WHERE [something] IN (" & Join(myRange, "", "") & ")"`   Assuming your values in the INare numeeric and don't need quotes.

Comment: Also:  `Set myRange = Sheets("Sheet9").Range("P2:P" & Lastrow)`